# Divide and Conquer from iterative

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Given an (1-based) array a with n elements and function f(i, j) (1 ≤ i, j ≤ n) as (i - j)2 + g(i, j)2. Function g is calculated by the following pseudo-code:

```
 int g(int i, int j)
 { 
   int sum = 0;
   for (int k = min(i, j) + 1; k <= max(i, j); k = k + 1)
     sum = sum + a[k];
   return sum; 
}
```

Find a value mini ≠ j f(i, j).

I have created a iterative brute force algorithm for this but the solution need to be coded in divide and conquer.

Brute force algo :

```
def g_fun(i,j):
    sum=0
    for k in xrange(min(i,j)+1,max(i,j)+1):
        sum+=arr[k-1]
    return sum

def f_fun(i,j):
    s=g_fun(i,j)
    return ((i-j)**2 + s**2)

n=input("n : ")
arr=map(int,raw_input("Array : ").split())
low=100000 #infinity
for i in xrange(1,n+1):
    for j in xrange(1,n+1):
        if i!=j:
            temp=f_fun(i,j)
            if temp < low:
                low=temp
print low
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to ask for ready and complete solutions. You must make an effort, by learning and coding. Only when you get stuck on your way in some specific part, then ask a question about that specific problem.

Comment: @Dialecticus : I understand sir, I came up with a iterative solution. Only thing I need is some directions about how to reach a solution